# jQuery flot multi bar chart side by side

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery plot with the categories plugin to create charts.
I want to plot two bars side by side for each month with this code:

```
$.plot(".chart", [ { label: "Neue Mitglieder", data: data, order: 1 }, { label: "Fällige Kündigungen", data: data2, order: 2 } ], {
        series: {
            bars: {
                show: true,
                barWidth: 0.5,
                align: "center",

            }
        },
        xaxis: {
            mode: "categories",
            ticks: [[0,"Jan"], [1,"Feb"],  [2,"Mär"],  [3,"Apr"],  [4,"Mai"],  
                    [5,"Jun"],  [6,"Jul"],  [7,"Aug"],  [8,"Sep"],  [9,"Okt"],  [10,"Nov"],  [11,"Dez"]],
            tickLength: 1,

        },
        grid: {
            hoverable: true,
        },
        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals:false,
    }
    });
```

And that's my result:

[image: plotting a chart]

The bars are still overlapping but I want my result to look like

[image: Correct chart]

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code? I thought the "order" option will fix that problem, but it didn't change anything.

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/buk8mhy8/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found 2 mistakes in your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buk8mhy8)

1. jquery.flot.orderBars.js link is wrong.
2. Removed order:1 and 2 from series data
3. updated your series default object with this

   ```
   series: {
     bars: {
       show: true,
       barWidth: 0.15,
       order: 1
     }
    }
   ```

   Check the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buk8mhy8/3/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still the same result. I think my bars object in declared in the series array globally, isn't it?

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle. so that we can pinpoint your problem.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I made the changes and now it looks like this: http://i.gyazo.com/120c967ee3239bb0ad8407d1567ec0b4.png I'm really confused, because it works find on the fiddle...

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot I posted, it still looks wrong :-( do you have any idea about this?

Comment: create new fiddle with your new code. I'll take a look

Comment: Oh man, I just changed the include order of the .js files from <script src="js/jquery.flot.orderBars.js"></script><script src="js/jquery.flot.categories.js"></script>
 to <script src="js/jquery.flot.categories.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flot.orderBars.js"></script> now it's working. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I tried to use orderBars plugin but the result was not what I expected. So what I did was:

1. Use the categories plugin
2. Define left and right align

obs: It works only with two bars side-by-side.

The Code:

```
var data1 = [ ["January", 10], ["February", 8], ["March", 4], ["April", 13], ["May", 17], ["June", 9] ];
var data2 = [ ["January", 1], ["February", 5], ["March", 6], ["April", 3], ["May", 37], ["June", 39] ];


$.plot($("#placeholder"), 
        [{  data: data1,
            bars: {
                show: true,
                barWidth: 0.2,
                align: "left",
            }
        },
        {
            data: data2,
            bars: {
                show: true,
                barWidth: 0.2,
                align: "right",
            }
        }
        ],
        {
            xaxis: {
                mode: "categories",
                tickLength: 0
            }
        }
);
```

The result:

[image: two bars]